# Xamarin UITest is failing with Exit Code 134 Visual Studio For Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I recently began getting Exit Code 134 errors while using Xamarin UITest in an iOS Simulator.
FYI The app runs fine in the simulator from VS4Mac 8.39 Build 2 I am on Mojave 10.14.6
I have tried various simulators in my dev environment.

I am using package Xamarin.UITest 3.04 from nugget
This is causing all sorts of problems in our dev team.
Previously the tests were working. I have confirmed

////Here is the Log.

10-12-2019 08:41:50.627 -08:00 - 1 - iOS test running Xamarin.UITest version: 3.0.4
10-12-2019 08:41:50.642 -08:00 - 16 - Skipping IDE integration as important properties are configured. To force IDE integration, add .PreferIdeSettings() to ConfigureApp.
10-12-2019 08:41:50.645 -08:00 - 19 - Skipping local screenshots. Can be enabled with EnableScreenshots() when configuring app.
10-12-2019 08:41:50.844 -08:00 - 218 - Artifact folder: /var/folders/3k/4bppd34512qgd7k87kwxmt900000gq/T/uitest/a-C499B8C71688C213537A093CC07CA776F65A8BE1
10-12-2019 08:41:51.098 -08:00 - 472 - Running command. { Path: "chmod", Arguments: "a+x /var/folders/3k/4bppd34512qgd7k87kwxmt900000gq/T/uitest/a-C499B8C71688C213537A093CC07CA776F65A8BE1/2807/idevice-tools/iappdata", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:51.127 -08:00 - 501 - Running command. { Path: "chmod", Arguments: "a+x /var/folders/3k/4bppd34512qgd7k87kwxmt900000gq/T/uitest/a-C499B8C71688C213537A093CC07CA776F65A8BE1/2807/idevice-tools/iproxy", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:51.940 -08:00 - 1313 - Artifact folder: /var/folders/3k/4bppd34512qgd7k87kwxmt900000gq/T/uitest/a-232637725EA33B0A0A28B472493782277BAC733E
10-12-2019 08:41:52.007 -08:00 - 1381 - Running command. { Path: "plutil", Arguments: "-convert xml1 -o - "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/PICTS/PICTS.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/PICTS.iOS.app/Info.plist"", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:52.142 -08:00 - 1516 - Running command. { Path: "xcrun", Arguments: "otool-classic -hv -arch all "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/PICTS/PICTS.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/PICTS.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Core.pdb"", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:52.905 -08:00 - 2279 - Running command. { Path: "xcrun", Arguments: "otool-classic -hv -arch all "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/PICTS/PICTS.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/PICTS.iOS.app/System.IO.Compression.pdb"", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:52.923 -08:00 - 2297 - Running command. { Path: "xcrun", Arguments: "otool-classic -hv -arch all "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/PICTS/PICTS.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/PICTS.iOS.app/System.Runtime.Serialization.pdb"", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:52.939 -08:00 - 2313 - Running command. { Path: "xcrun", Arguments: "otool-classic -hv -arch all "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/PICTS/PICTS.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/PICTS.iOS.app/Rg.Plugins.Popup.IOS.pdb"", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:52.955 -08:00 - 2329 - Running command. { Path: "xcrun", Arguments: "otool-classic -hv -arch all "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/PICTS/PICTS.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/PICTS.iOS.app/mscorlib.pdb"", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:52.971 -08:00 - 2345 - Running command. { Path: "xcrun", Arguments: "otool-classic -hv -arch all "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/PICTS/PICTS.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/PICTS.iOS.app/PICTS.iOS"", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:52.984 -08:00 - 2358 - Running command. { Path: "xcrun", Arguments: "strings "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/PICTS/PICTS.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/PICTS.iOS.app/PICTS.iOS"", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:53.625 -08:00 - 2999 - Starting app bundle.  { AppBundle: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/PICTS/PICTS.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/PICTS.iOS.app" }
10-12-2019 08:41:53.627 -08:00 - 3000 - Running command. { Path: "ps", Arguments: "-xww -o pid,user,args", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:53.650 -08:00 - 3024 - Running command. { Path: "ps", Arguments: "-xww -o pid,user,args", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:53.675 -08:00 - 3049 - Running command. { Path: "/usr/bin/xcrun", Arguments: "simctl help 2>&1", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:54.219 -08:00 - 3593 - Running command. { Path: "/usr/bin/xcrun", Arguments: "simctl list devices --json", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:54.398 -08:00 - 3771 - Running command. { Path: "/usr/bin/xcrun", Arguments: "--sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-platform-version", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:55.232 -08:00 - 4606 - Running command. { Path: "ps", Arguments: "-xww -o pid,user,args", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:55.257 -08:00 - 4631 - Running command. { Path: "plutil", Arguments: "-convert xml1 -o - "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/PICTS/PICTS.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/PICTS.iOS.app/Info.plist"", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:55.270 -08:00 - 4644 - Running command. { Path: "plutil", Arguments: "-convert xml1 -o - "/Users/markwardell/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F37FBC6D-9F08-4DE2-8424-2084B3CD8710/device.plist"", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:55.286 -08:00 - 4660 - Running command. { Path: "plutil", Arguments: "-convert xml1 -o - "/Users/markwardell/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F37FBC6D-9F08-4DE2-8424-2084B3CD8710/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EC787E4A-E4EE-45CF-854B-19C9FA66AD09/PICTS.iOS.app/Info.plist"", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:55.301 -08:00 - 4674 - Running command. { Path: "plutil", Arguments: "-convert xml1 -o - "/Users/markwardell/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F37FBC6D-9F08-4DE2-8424-2084B3CD8710/data/Containers/Data/Application/82074D08-DD20-410C-A028-AFD27716C1C0/.com.apple.mobile_container_manager.metadata.plist"", CurrentDirectory: "/Users/markwardell/Documents/NewUITestpicts_mobile/Tests/PICTS.UITests/bin/Debug" }
10-12-2019 08:41:56.433 -08:00 - 5807 - Sim check: Not up to date. Target hash: F28409FD2189FB34861CC2FA9EE4113751785686 - Installed hash: DB315C69B5F92BAB8D98FBF80BCE1EFFFA0E185F
10-12-2019 08:41:56.433 -08:00 - 5807 - Deleting: /Users/markwardell/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F37FBC6D-9F08-4DE2-8424-2084B3CD8710/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EC787E4A-E4EE-45CF-854B-19C9FA66AD09
10-12-2019 08:41:56.445 -08:00 - 5818 - 1 - Launching simulator if not already running
10-12-2019 08:41:56.943 -08:00 - 6316 - Running: /var/folders/3k/4bppd34512qgd7k87kwxmt900000gq/T/xdb/DeviceAgent.iOS.Dependencies/0a3ddc92d1ddf25e2059c72229db762c/bin/iOSDeviceManager launch-simulator -d F37FBC6D-9F08-4DE2-8424-2084B3CD8710
10-12-2019 08:41:57.439 -08:00 - 6812 - Exit code '134' received from '/var/folders/3k/4bppd34512qgd7k87kwxmt900000gq/T/xdb/DeviceAgent.iOS.Dependencies/0a3ddc92d1ddf25e2059c72229db762c/bin/iOSDeviceManager launch-simulator -d F37FBC6D-9F08-4DE2-8424-2084B3CD8710'

**Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
  Referenced from: /var/folders/3k/4bppd34512qgd7k87kwxmt900000gq/T/xdb/DeviceAgent.iOS.Dependencies/0a3ddc92d1ddf25e2059c72229db762c/bin/iOSDeviceManager
    /private/var/folders/3k/4bppd34512qgd7k87kwxmt900000gq/T/xdb/DeviceAgent.iOS.Dependencies/0a3ddc92d1ddf25e2059c72229db762c/bin/../Frameworks/FBControlCore.framework/Versions/A/FBControlCore: code signature invalid for '/private/var/folders/3k/4bppd34512qgd7k87kwxmt900000gq/T/xdb/DeviceAgent.iOS.Dependencies/0a3ddc92d1ddf25e2059c72229db762c/bin/../Frameworks/FBControlCore.framework/Versions/A/FBControlCore'
    /private/var/folders/3k/4bppd34512qgd7k87kwxmt900000gq/T/xdb/DeviceAgent.iOS.Dependencies/0a3ddc92d1ddf25e2059c72229db762c/bin/../Frameworks/FBControlCore.framework/Versions/A/FBControlCore: stat() failed with errno=1
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBControlCore.framework/Versions/A/FBControlCore**

Comment: Hi , Did the previous version run successfully? From the error log `no suitable image found.` ,I think this problem should be about image .

Comment: yes... v 3.02 worked fine.  this was an issue v 3.04 was an issue fixed in v 3.0.5

Comment: Okey , you mean the latest version has fixed it . That's great ! Remember to update it as an answer when you have time .

Answer (score 1):

Just update the version of your UITest NuGet package, since the updating the version created the issue.